# XNA: Polygon Source from Texture2D

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, texture2d, spritebatch

I've got a problem. Using SpriteBatch, I can only draw a rectangle area from my source Texture2D.

Please, help me to find the way, how I can draw polygon or circle area from my source texture.
I'm creating 2d sprite game.

Thanks in advance,
Denis

Comment: Wow I was just about to ask the same question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct this shapes with dynamic vertices, like building your own shapes [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975156%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) 
But if you just want to draw any non rectangular shapes it would be much easier if you just use transparency. So you will still take a rectangular region from your texture but only the circle/polygon is visible.
This can be done easily by using png ord tga with baked in transparency. There are also a lot of qeustions dealing with this on SO:
[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2656835/xna-alpha-blending-to-make-part-of-a-texture-transparent) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975250/xna-how-to-make-transparent-texture)

Comment: Oh, great! Thank a lot, it will be usefull!